# Taking a file from my terminal window and store it on my mac

Tags: macos, mac, unix, file-transfer

I am a little confused on how i am suppose to get a file from my terminal window on my mac that I want to have/need to use on a different applicatopn (APLX) in order to edit this file. I was wondering if it is:

```
scp username@userhost.edu:directory/file file
```

Is this the right command to use to get a specific file onto my mac itself?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the following command to copy a remote file to your local Mac:

```
scp [username]@[server address]:[path to source file] [destination directory]
```

For example:

```
scp john@192.168.1.1:~/Desktop/file.zip ~/Desktop/
```

That should do it!

Comment: Okay, if i am logged onto a school account and want to transfer this file to my mac, would this be the same process. Say from my student account for my class?

Comment: If you are ssh'd into the remote server, you would modify the command a bit: 

    scp  [path to source file] [username]@[you mac's ip address]:[destination directory]    

For example:

    scp ~/Desktop/file.zip john@192.168.1.1:~/Desktop/    

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `scp` should do the trick.

```
scp username@host:~/test.txt ~/Downloads/
```

That will copy `test.txt` from my server to my local drive (to my Downloads folder).

In the Terminal, you can do this to see the `scp` manual:

```
man scp
```

There are a lot more examples [on this page](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php).

Comment: Okay, if i am logged onto a school account and want to transfer this file to my mac, would this be the same process. Say from my student account for my class?